# How to infer type from subclass in Typescript when methods argument and return type does not extend each other

Tags: typescript

**What I am trying to achieve**: I want to have bacis `ChangeListener` withe method `saveChanges` that receives value of type T and returns save value. Also I want to have `ChangeListenerWithModifier` that overrides `ChangeListener` class and extends `saveChanges` method. In this case value type is T, but it passes different value type to parent `saveChanges` method.

```
class ChangeListener<T, R = T> {
    changes: R;

    saveChanges(value: T): R {
        this.changes = value;
        return value;
    }
}

class ChangeListnerWithModifier<T, B> extends ChangeListener<B> {
    constructor(private modifier: (value: T) => B) {
        super();
    }

    saveChanges(value: T): B {
        return super.saveChanges(this.modifier(value));
    }
}
```

With my current setup I receive error in `ChangeListener` saveChanges method

> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'.
> 'R' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T'. This type parameter might need an extends R constraint.

I understand this error, but this is exactly what I need. My return type might be the same as T but it can be completely different type, not extending T.

Also there is an error it `ChangeListnerWithModifier` saveChanges method

> Property 'saveChanges' in type 'ChangeListnerWithModifier<T, B>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'ChangeListener<B, B>'.
> Type '(value: T) => B' is not assignable to type '(value: B) => B'.
> Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'B'.ts(2416)

I could go with different approach and use single type in `ChangeListener` parent class

```
class ChangeListener<T> {
    changes: T;

    saveChanges(value: T): T {
        this.changes = value;
        return value;
    }
}

class ChangeListnerWithModifier<T, B> extends ChangeListener<B> {
    constructor(private modifier: (value: T) => B) {
        super();
    }

    saveChanges(value: T): B {
        return super.saveChanges(this.modifier(value));
    }
}
```

But then there is issues extending that class and overriding it's methods with different return type signature. Now saveChanges in children class gives me type error:

> Property 'saveChanges' in type 'ChangeListnerWithModifier<T, B>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'ChangeListener'.
> Type '(value: T) => B' is not assignable to type '(value: B) => B'.
> Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'B'.ts(2416)

Comment: Your `ChangeListenerWithModifier` is not a proper subtype of `ChangeListener`, so what you're trying to do is actively hostile to the TS type system. (if you have `class Foo extends Bar {`, then you need to write `const bar: Bar = new Foo()` and have everything work out for `bar`). Inheritance is not the right way for this to work (at least for types). Consider using [composition instead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/Wzqk4m). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, composition is ok for this code, but my actual code has many more methods in parent class that I want to inherit and I need to pass my custom changelistener to components that accept ChangeListener type only, hence I need to extend that class.

Comment: • "many more methods" yes, composition is generally tedious in this case, but that doesn't change the answer, only the desirability. • "components that accept ChangeListener" Then what you want is unsafe. If something only accepts `ChangeListener` then it *should not* accept a `ChangeListenerWithModifier` for the reason I mentioned at the top. Something accepting `ChangeListener<T>` will expect that `saveChanges()` accepts a `T`, not some other random type. How do you propose that your other components know what to pass `saveChanges()`? • How shall we proceed here?

Comment: @jcalz, thanks for clarification. I decided to go with composition and create interface that will be implemented by change listeners.

Comment: Okay, I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't implement this is because it's not type safe.  A `ChangeListener<T>` must have a `saveChanges()` method that accepts a `T`.  If `ChangeListnerWithModifier<U, T> extends ChangeListener<T>`, then its `saveChange()` method must *also* accept a `T`. If it doesn't, then you run the real risk of someone asking for a `ChangeListener<string>`, taking the `ChangeListenerWithModifier<number, string>` you give them, calling `saveChange("xyz")`, and watching some kind of crazy runtime problem that occurs:

```
function foo(x: ChangeListener<string>) {
   x.saveChanges("abc");
}
const m = new ChangeListnerWithModifier((value: number) => value.toFixed(1));

foo(m); // if this were acceptable, you'd get a runtime error
```

You can try to push this inconsistency around, but it won't fix the problem if you continue to try to use inheritance for this.

---

If you want to get type safety, then you'll need to refactor what you're doing in some way. One standard approach in situations like this is to favor [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Instead of `ChangeListnerWithModifier` *being* a `ChangeListener`, you make it so that it *has* a `ChangeListener`.  That could look like:

```
class ChangeListnerWithModifier<U, T>{

    private innerListener: ChangeListener<T> = new ChangeListener<T>();

    constructor(private modifier: (value: U) => T) {
    }

    saveChanges(value: U): T {
        return this.innerListener.saveChanges(this.modifier(value));
    }
}
```

Now there's no pressure to try to force `saveChanges()` to do two different incompatible things.  And you could define some interface that both a `ChangeListnerWithModifier<U, T>` and a `ChangeListener<T>` support, depending on your use case. There are certainly drawbacks to composition, but it's a common option to pursue.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAhEATJBvAUE-S8ANiFFEgMIAWIwA5hADICWUALhMBAE4A8AKgD5seAmPg160AIQAuJPwDcOUWPxQQANwjVaDKAApNIIgFcI8-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-yRmwxhMpjM5gtkJDVjwNg2dpqDrTh1RAha07RVtleZsS2CUIBzdVwtx4HcARAlkwXdFwP3lMDLUA5IgA)